# Do Path skill chances cap off at a certain point?

Tags: octopath-traveler

With Therion, your path skill lets you steal from random people, and Cyrus lets you inspect people. I haven't noticed that the chances of these abilities get much better with level.

For example, I found a kid with lots of *great* things to Steal, but they were all 8% or less, but it was pretty much the same for the levels I checked him at. Cyrus seems about the same, where it seems like the "person" dictates the chance of succeeding.

Do the Path skills have a soft cap? What is it based on?

Comment: I’m still experimenting and am thus not prepared to make a true answer, but so far, anecdotally, it’s based on character level, it increases in stages (8% one level, 45% the next in one case), and seems to be an opposed check on some kind, the exact same item having different chances in different cities, though they seem consistent within the same city. Again, its early days, this is all based on feel, and should not be considered authoritative.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. From what I'm seeing so far, some of the 3% steals have graduated up to 8%, but I haven't seen much higher than that. There's also some intermediate steps like 15%. I'm guessing it's based on the average party level and how "useful" a particular item would be to the party (super strong items have 0-3% steal - not sure if the 0% ones ever go up though).

Comment: Still compiling data, but some of the “tier 2” towns have NPCs that give “Thief Tips” when investigated which seems to give a global bonus to stealing (as opposed to the local bonuses to Challenge, Allure, etc).